# How to pass an element onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Actually i'm trying to pass a td element with which i have to do some operations on a td click or better i have a function where i use the following code

```
 var tr = document.getElementById($('#tavolo').val());
  $(`td:eq(${inizio})`, tr).css('background-color', 'red') .attr("onclick","Elimina('" + tr + "');");
```

when the user will click a td it will open a modal and then in that modal there is a button that call another function which will delete some elements from that td.

The issue is that "[object HTMLTableRowElement]" is passed as tr element so i'm unable to make any operation on it.

If it's usefull here is the function Elimina

```
function Elimina(tr) {
    $('#del').attr("onclick", "eliminaPrenotazione('" + tr + "');");
}
```

While here is the function eliminaPrenotazione

```
function eliminaPrenotazione(tr) {
var start = 1;

        for (i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
            $(`td:eq(${start})`, tr).css('background-color', 'white').removeAttr("class").find('span').remove();
        }
    }
```

Here is html code of what td looks like ( i can't post all html as it has 96 similar td's)

```
<td style="padding: 0px; position: relative; background-color: red;" class="48:15" data-inizio="12:00" data-fine="16:00" onclick="Elimina('48:15','Ihor','12:00','16:00','[object HTMLTableRowElement]');"><span class="tag" style="width: 160px; overflow: hidden;" onmouseover="highlight(this);" onmouseout="unhighlight(this)">Ihor</span></td>
```

Comment: please share the html

Comment: Why are you mixing DOM and jquery. Pick one. Why are you adding an event handler with attr? You should be using on or click/.

Comment: @epascarello actually i couldn't use click as it's dynamically created table and just specific td on it will have the onclick, is it a bad practise to mix DOM and jquery?

Comment: @brk added the code of how's td looks like

Comment: if its dynamicly generated table, add click event listener to its parent, since javascript is a big fan of event bubling, you will catch the click event there.

Comment: Instead of passing the string `'[object HTMLTableRowElement]'`, you can get the row element to pass (I'm assuming the parent row of the clicked `td`), with an expression as simple as `event.target.parentNode`. (At least that's how it looks in vanilla JS, if you gave your click listener a parameter called `event`.)

Comment: @Cat so something like "$(this).closest('tr').attr("val")" in jquery right?

Comment: *"couldn't use click as it's dynamically created table"* huh? If you can do `...attr("onclick",` then you can do `...on("click",`

Comment: Yeah, that looks right if `val` is the attribute you're trying to access. I doubt it would give you a reference to the `tr` object itself though.

Comment: If you want the `tr`, you'd probably do `$(this).parent` or `$(this).closest('tr')`. But in any case, you'll have a jQuery collection at that point (albeit one that contains a single element) and you'll have to get the (first) element out of the collection -- possibly by just appending `[0]` to your selector, but I'm not sure about this since I don't use jQuery much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to give you an indication to try to put you on the right way.

You can to do something looks like that :

```
$("#yourBtnID").click(function(elem){
   $("#yourDivID").append("<td>" + elem + "</td>");
});
```

it will add a line td to the each click basically

Now you can try to modify your own code and come back if you don't succeed

Good luck ;)

Comment: Actually i'm yet using the click on the form button but it's a timeline where the clickable td will be created dynamically or load from the server

Comment: yes i saw, i meant you have to use append function for example because it adds on DOM for each click